# Updating Ember-CLI fails

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to update ember-cli (and then ember in my projects) following these instructions:
https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases
and
http://emberigniter.com/update-latest-ember-data-cli/

which tells me to do:

```
npm uninstall -g ember-cli
npm cache clean
bower cache clean
npm install -g ember-cli@2.5.0
```

This is finishing *without errors*. I just got a warning:

> npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package has been
>   discontinued...
>   npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will
>   0.0 as soon as...

When I then do a

```
ember -v
```

afterwards I still get

```
version: 1.13.7
node: 4.2.1
npm: 2.13.3
os: win32 x64 // win10
```

Any suggestions why I cant get ember-cli updated?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself:

doing `ember -v` *inside* an ember-project folder will return the version of ember (project), not of ember-cli. So getting out of that folder, doing another ´ember -v` gave me the updated version of ember-cli 2.5.0

Comment: did you change the version of ember-cli in your package.json?